Load Excel using office.js
I want to load excel worksheet using office.js API. This excel contains chart so can't load excel using workbook.insertWorksheetsFromBase64 API.
We tried workbook.insertWorksheetsFromBase64 API. But this API does not support loading excel containing chart in online office .
